# PHP: Output submitted form text into hidden input field for submission again

Tags: php, html, forms, escaping

I am creating an HTML form (to send a plain text email, using Swift Mailer ..but that's not important right now), using PHP server-side, where I want to display the user's text input for them to finally confirm before actually sending the email.

I use `nl2br(htmlspecialchars())` to display the user's form field input safely, and then need to output that input into an `<input type="hidden" ../>` form field to be submitted again for actually creating the email.

The email body can obviously contain all sorts of potentially troublesome characters such as single and double quotes, ampersands, less-then and greater-than symbols.

In the context of my input field, am I right in thinking that my sole(?) problem is ensuring that the form quotes around `value=".."` (I usually use double quotes) and any quote characters in the input string value don't clash with each other? Is there a PHP function along similar lines to `htmlspecialchars` which will escape quotes as necessary? I don't want to convert anything into HTML entities as the email that I will be sending will be plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the function `String addslashes( $str )` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.addslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

After much further perusal of the PHP manual, it looks as though I can use [`htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to safely encode my text for the form field, and then use (the "relatively" new corresponding reverse function) [`htmlspecialchars_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to convert the HTML entities safely back to normal characters again, when creating the plain text email message.

Comment: Why is it so often the case that you finally come across the section of the documentation that provides an answer not long **after** you post a question?!

Comment: If this isn't the correct or most appropriate solution, I would still be grateful for any other answers that may be better. Thanks!